# Drive has a code instead of its normal name

Tags: drive, rename

One of my Hard Disk drives has a code instead of its normal name when I get its address. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: What would be the "normal name"? You'd probably have to change its label.

Comment: In the picture above the normal name will be `Less Fair`, the name manually assigned to the drive.

Comment: How did you assign this name? Does it have more than one partition? What filesystem is it formatted in?

Comment: It is assigned with gparted label change. it's NTFS.

Comment: Seems like it already had an assigned mountpoint when you changed its label. Try running `sudo mv /media/username/CE78C35078C335CD /media/username/CE78C35078C335CD.old` (replacing `username` with your actual username) to see if that works.

Comment: This is not such folder  CE78C35078C335CD.

Answer (score 0):

It was so because I had turned on automount using gnome-disks. One should also correct mount point folder when turning automount on:
[image]